# First time setting a gameobject to active it lags

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When I first set a particular gameobject in the Canvas element to active, (SetActive(true)), it lags for a good second or so. Sequential activations are instantaneous. Note that this only happens in the standalone player. In the editor, it doesn't lag at all. My guess is obviously that the first time it has to load the asset. However, can I preload this particular asset in any way? I attempted to do so in the build settings under optimization, but that didn't affect anything. And no, I don't have any code in the Start() function or the OnEnable() function of the said gameobject that's being enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The accepted answer is a workaround, not a solution. Keeping hundreds of UI elements loaded is an utter waste of memory.

You should instead divide up your canvases, as written in [this wonderful article](https://unity3d.com/how-to/unity-ui-optimization-tips) by Unity. The reason for the lag is Unity's updating all canvas contents, even disabled objects, when you enable an object for the first time. To prevent unused objects from updating, isolate them in a different canvases. You can even put those canvases as children of your original canvas if you wish.

Comment: Neat. I don't believe this information was around back then. Also, I'm a much better coder now. I wouldn't do it like that anymore. ;P

Answer (score 1):

That's expected.The lag depends on how many `UI` components and GameObjects that are under the hierarchy of the `Canvas`. There is so much memory allocation and draw calls when `SetActive(true)` is used on a `Canvas` or UI component. The fix is simple. Instead of using `SetActive(true)` for UI, disable the component by modifying the `enabled` property.

For example, to enable/disable the the `Canvas`:

```
Canvas canvas;
canvas.enabled = true; //Enable
canvas.enabled = false; //Disable
```

Let's say that you only want to disable a `Text` component under a `Canvas`, use the `enabled` property to disable that `Text` component instead of `SetActive(true)`. The-same thing applies to other UI components.

Comment: Do I need a using directive to use that? Unity's not happy about it. I tried using the 'enabled = false;' on a GameObject that I declared and it's not liking it.

Comment: You need to import Unity UI with `using UnityEngine.UI`. You also need to make `canvas` variable public so that you can assign it from the editor.... Also `canvas.enabled = true;` and `canvas.enabled = false;` must be put in a function.

Comment: I think you're mis-understanding my question. There's a gameobject that contains other elements inside of it that I want to enable/disable. The canvas is always enabled, as there are other things on there as well. 'enabled' does not seem to exist for GameObjects.

Comment: I understand our question. Please read my answer again. You have objects under your Canvas that causes freeze when enabled/disabled with `SetActive(true)`. You can fix this by using the `enabled` on the `component` **not** GameObject. The example I provided is for `Canvas` but will work with components under it such as `Text`,`Image`,`RawImage` `Slider` if you replace Canvas with any of them. If this is a 3D Mesh you want to disable, you can also use the component. You will get freezes if you disable UI Objects or GameObjects under UI Canvas with  `SetActive(true)`.

Comment: Yeah, but I'd rather not reference every single component in my scene, especially because I have to find them through tags 'cause I switch scenes sometimes with "DontDestroyOnLoad" 'n stuff. It's not viable at all to enable every single component under the Canvas that I need.   Thanks for your help, but I already solved it anyway.

Comment: Your solution does not solve this problem and you will likely see more freezes on some plaftorms. If you still don't understand what I am saying, feel free to put a screenshot of the object you want to disable that is under the Canvas and I will show you how to disable it.

Comment: I highly doubt that I'll get more freezes, but thanks for your concern. My solution may be hacky, I'll admit, but it solves the problem simply. My project is not graphics heavy at all, I just need it not to lag the first time it shows up. I've tested it already on standalone, which is the only platform I'm planning for, and it works great.

Comment: Everything you said in your second to last comment is `false` because there is something called `getComponent` but since, your problem is fixed, that's fine. Happy coding!

Comment: Forgive me, I didn't mean component as in the way Unity meant it. I meant objects.